# Get the first n/2 of n words in a column in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the first n/2 of n words in a column in a pandas data frame.
Each row can have a different number of words, but every row has an even number of words.
This column contains the name of an item, but every name is duplicated.
For example, `One` became `One One` and `One Two` became `One Two One Two`.

I thought the following would work.

1. count the number of words
2. split the column on spaces
3. get the first n/2 words in this split

But it doesn't work (I only casually use Python and pandas).
Here is an MWE.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['One One', 'One Two One Two'])
df[1] = df[0].str.count('\w+')
df[2] = df[0].str.split()
df[3] = df[0].get(df[2])
```

P.S. Please let me know if you have a good reference on pandas for the R user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['One One', 'One Two One Two'])

def proc(s):
    l = s.split()
    return ' '.join(l[:len(l) // 2])

df[1] = [proc(s) for s in df[0].values.tolist()]

                 0        1
0          One One      One
1  One Two One Two  One Two
```

Answer (score 3):

Base on you previous effort :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['One One', 'One Two One Two'])
df[1] = df[0].str.count('\w+')
df[2] = df[0].str.split()
df[3]=df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[2][:int((x[1]/2))]), axis=1)

df
Out[354]: 
                 0  1                     2        3
0          One One  2            [One, One]      One
1  One Two One Two  4  [One, Two, One, Two]  One Two
```

My solution(Base on what you mentioned *Each row can have a different number of words, but every row has an even number of words. This column contains the name of an item, but every name is duplicated.*) :

```
df['Target']= df.apply(lambda x: x[0][:int((len(x[0])+1)/2)], axis=1)


df
Out[389]: 
                 0    Target
0          One One      One 
1  One Two One Two  One Two
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df[column_name].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[:2]))
```

this takes the first n (2 in this above case) from the column names listed in the dataframe.

Comment: please consider adding some explanation to your solution for others to understand what and why you did it